# get_var is neither a string, integer, or array ...?

Tags: wp-query, mysql, wpdb

```
$vote_count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT votes FROM wp_mytable WHERE product = %s AND
                              company = %s", $product, $company));
        if(is_int($vote_count)){
            $html = '<a href="#" class="vote_for_doc">
            Vote here</a> (<span class="vote-count">' . $vote_count . '</span> Votes for ' . $product . ' and ' . $company . ')';
        }else{
            if(is_string($vote_count)){
                $html = '$vote_count is a string in the database<p>' . print_r($vote_count);
            }if(is_array($vote_count)){
                $html = '$vote_count is an array in the database<p>' . print_r($vote_count);
            }else{
                $html = '$vote_count is not a string or an integer<p>' . print_r($vote_count);
            }
        }
```

And my output:

> $vote_count is not a string or an integer
>
> 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var_dump($vote_count) should tell you what type $vote_count is. Probably you're getting NULL.

Comment: Yes, it's NULL. Why would I get NULL if it returns '1'?

Comment: Oh I see, I just switched from get_var to get_results and it worked.